# How to dynamically create this Object for taffyDB query

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, taffydb

I have a taffyDB filled with productdata and want to do a query to select all products with a range between >2 and <=4

```
   allProducts = TAFFY([
    {OrderNo:'prod1',range: 3,Status:'inactive'},
    {OrderNo:'prod2',range: 2,Status:'inactive'},
    {OrderNo:'prod3',range: 2,Status:'inactive'},
    {OrderNo:'prod4',range: 6,Status:'inactive'},
    {OrderNo:'prod5',range: 5,Status:'inactive'},
```

I know can easily do this with this query:

```
allProducts({range:{gt:2}},{range:{lte:4}}).get();
```

but how do I dynamically construct this query with values from two dropdownboxes?
I can't think of a way to achieve it because I think I can't creat an object which has 2 properties with the same name :/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create an object with two properties with the same name. Just do something like this:

```
//assuming minValue and maxValue are defined
var lowerRange = {range: {gt: minValue}};
var upperRange = {range: {lte: maxValue}};
var results = allProducts(lowerRange, upperRange).get();
```